# clFFT compilation issue : undefined reference to `clGetPlatformInfo' and other OpenCL functions

Tags: cmake, compiler-errors, shared-libraries, opencl

I try to build `clFFT` library (for doing FFT with OpenCL) and examples contained into `clFFT git`.

1. First, into `/opt/`, I did :

`git clone https://github.com/clMathLibraries/clFFT.git`

2. After, always into `/opt/` directory, I did : `$ mkdir build && cd build/`
3. from here, I called `cmake` like this :

`cmake -DOpenCL_INCLUDE_DIR=/opt/AMDAPPSDK-3.0/include -DOpenCL_LIBRARY=/opt/AMDAPPSDK-3.0/lib/x86_64 ../clFFT/src/`

Indeed, into `/opt/` directory, I have installed `AMDAPPSDK-3.0`from the `AMD-APP-SDKInstaller-v3.0.130.136-GA-linux64.tar.bz2`archive.

4. Everything seems to be valid for the compilation of clFFT but it fails :

4.1) First, at the end of `cmake`command above, I get :

```
 cmake -DOpenCL_INCLUDE_DIR=/opt/AMDAPPSDK-3.0/include -DOpenCL_LIBRARY=/opt/AMDAPPSDK-3.0/lib/x86_64 ../clFFT/src/
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 8.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 8.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- UNICODE feature disabled on linux
-- 64bit build - FIND_LIBRARY_USE_LIB64_PATHS TRUE
-- Could NOT find Boost
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:146 (message):
  Try setting Boost_DEBUG and Boost_DETAILED_FAILURE_MSG for more information


-- Looking for CL_VERSION_2_2
-- Looking for CL_VERSION_2_2 - not found
-- Looking for CL_VERSION_2_1
-- Looking for CL_VERSION_2_1 - not found
-- Looking for CL_VERSION_2_0
-- Looking for CL_VERSION_2_0 - found
-- Found OpenCL: /opt/AMDAPPSDK-3.0/lib/x86_64 (found version "2.0") 
-- Found FFTW: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3f.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3.so  
-- Detected GNU fortran compiler.
-- CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER flags: -m64 -pthread 
-- CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER debug flags: -g
-- CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER release flags: -O3 -DNDEBUG
-- CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER relwithdebinfo flags: -O2 -g -DNDEBUG
-- CMAKE_EXE_LINKER link flags: 
FFT clients will NOT be built
GoogleTest unit tests will NOT be built
FFT callback client will NOT be built
-- Configuring done
WARNING: Target "clFFT" requests linking to directory "/opt/AMDAPPSDK-3.0/lib/x86_64".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.
WARNING: Target "clFFT" requests linking to directory "/opt/AMDAPPSDK-3.0/lib/x86_64".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.
WARNING: Target "StatTimer" requests linking to directory "/opt/AMDAPPSDK-3.0/lib/x86_64".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.
WARNING: Target "StatTimer" requests linking to directory "/opt/AMDAPPSDK-3.0/lib/x86_64".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.
WARNING: Target "example_examples_fft2d" requests linking to directory "/opt/AMDAPPSDK-3.0/lib/x86_64".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.
WARNING: Target "example_examples_fft3d" requests linking to directory "/opt/AMDAPPSDK-3.0/lib/x86_64".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.
WARNING: Target "example_examples_fft1d" requests linking to directory "/opt/AMDAPPSDK-3.0/lib/x86_64".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /opt/build
```

more precisely, I am talking about :

```
-- Configuring done
WARNING: Target "clFFT" requests linking to directory "/opt/AMDAPPSDK-3.0/lib/x86_64".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.
WARNING: Target "clFFT" requests linking to directory "/opt/AMDAPPSDK-3.0/lib/x86_64".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.
WARNING: Target "StatTimer" requests linking to directory "/opt/AMDAPPSDK-3.0/lib/x86_64".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.
WARNING: Target "StatTimer" requests linking to directory "/opt/AMDAPPSDK-3.0/lib/x86_64".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.
WARNING: Target "example_examples_fft2d" requests linking to directory "/opt/AMDAPPSDK-3.0/lib/x86_64".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.
WARNING: Target "example_examples_fft3d" requests linking to directory "/opt/AMDAPPSDK-3.0/lib/x86_64".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.
WARNING: Target "example_examples_fft1d" requests linking to directory "/opt/AMDAPPSDK-3.0/lib/x86_64".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /opt/build
```

4.2) After launching `make`into `/opt/build/` directory, I get the following warnings :

```
$ make
Scanning dependencies of target clFFT
[  3%] Building CXX object library/CMakeFiles/clFFT.dir/transform.cpp.o
In file included from /opt/clFFT/src/library/repo.h:26,
                 from /opt/clFFT/src/library/transform.cpp:23:
/opt/clFFT/src/library/../statTimer/statisticalTimer.GPU.h:132:42: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument âcl_uintâ {aka âunsigned intâ} [-Wignored-attributes]
  typedef std::pair< std::string, cl_uint > idPair;
                                          ^
[  7%] Building CXX object library/CMakeFiles/clFFT.dir/accessors.cpp.o
In file included from /opt/clFFT/src/library/repo.h:26,
                 from /opt/clFFT/src/library/accessors.cpp:23:
/opt/clFFT/src/library/../statTimer/statisticalTimer.GPU.h:132:42: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument âcl_uintâ {aka âunsigned intâ} [-Wignored-attributes]
  typedef std::pair< std::string, cl_uint > idPair;
                                          ^
[ 11%] Building CXX object library/CMakeFiles/clFFT.dir/plan.cpp.o
In file included from /opt/clFFT/src/library/repo.h:26,
                 from /opt/clFFT/src/library/plan.cpp:25:
/opt/clFFT/src/library/../statTimer/statisticalTimer.GPU.h:132:42: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument âcl_uintâ {aka âunsigned intâ} [-Wignored-attributes]
  typedef std::pair< std::string, cl_uint > idPair;
                                          ^
[ 15%] Building CXX object library/CMakeFiles/clFFT.dir/repo.cpp.o
In file included from /opt/clFFT/src/library/repo.h:26,
                 from /opt/clFFT/src/library/repo.cpp:22:

...
```

and finally, I get the following ending errors :

```
[ 80%] Building C object examples/CMakeFiles/example_examples_fft2d.dir/fft2d.c.o
/opt/clFFT/src/examples/fft2d.c: In function âmainâ:
/opt/clFFT/src/examples/fft2d.c:63:5: warning: âclCreateCommandQueueâ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     queue = clCreateCommandQueue( ctx, device, 0, &err );
     ^~~~~
In file included from /opt/clFFT/src/include/clFFT.h:33,
                 from /opt/clFFT/src/examples/fft2d.c:21:
/opt/AMDAPPSDK-3.0/include/CL/cl.h:1359:1: note: declared here
 clCreateCommandQueue(cl_context                     /* context */,
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ 84%] Linking C executable examples/fft2d
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/example_examples_fft2d.dir/fft2d.c.o: in function `main':
fft2d.c:(.text.startup+0x76): undefined reference to `clGetPlatformIDs'
/usr/bin/ld: fft2d.c:(.text.startup+0x9d): undefined reference to `clGetPlatformInfo'
/usr/bin/ld: fft2d.c:(.text.startup+0xd1): undefined reference to `clGetDeviceIDs'
/usr/bin/ld: fft2d.c:(.text.startup+0xf6): undefined reference to `clGetDeviceInfo'
/usr/bin/ld: fft2d.c:(.text.startup+0x13c): undefined reference to `clCreateContext'
/usr/bin/ld: fft2d.c:(.text.startup+0x152): undefined reference to `clCreateCommandQueue'
/usr/bin/ld: fft2d.c:(.text.startup+0x215): undefined reference to `clCreateBuffer'
/usr/bin/ld: fft2d.c:(.text.startup+0x241): undefined reference to `clEnqueueWriteBuffer'
/usr/bin/ld: fft2d.c:(.text.startup+0x307): undefined reference to `clFinish'
/usr/bin/ld: fft2d.c:(.text.startup+0x334): undefined reference to `clEnqueueReadBuffer'
/usr/bin/ld: fft2d.c:(.text.startup+0x3a7): undefined reference to `clReleaseMemObject'
/usr/bin/ld: fft2d.c:(.text.startup+0x3cc): undefined reference to `clReleaseCommandQueue'
/usr/bin/ld: fft2d.c:(.text.startup+0x3d5): undefined reference to `clReleaseContext'
/usr/bin/ld: ../library/libclFFT.so.2.14.0: undefined reference to `clBuildProgram'
/usr/bin/ld: ../library/libclFFT.so.2.14.0: undefined reference to `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel'
/usr/bin/ld: ../library/libclFFT.so.2.14.0: undefined reference to `clSetKernelArg'
/usr/bin/ld: ../library/libclFFT.so.2.14.0: undefined reference to `clGetCommandQueueInfo'
/usr/bin/ld: ../library/libclFFT.so.2.14.0: undefined reference to `clReleaseEvent'
/usr/bin/ld: ../library/libclFFT.so.2.14.0: undefined reference to `clGetProgramBuildInfo'
/usr/bin/ld: ../library/libclFFT.so.2.14.0: undefined reference to `clGetContextInfo'
/usr/bin/ld: ../library/libclFFT.so.2.14.0: undefined reference to `clCreateProgramWithBinary'
/usr/bin/ld: ../library/libclFFT.so.2.14.0: undefined reference to `clRetainContext'
/usr/bin/ld: ../library/libclFFT.so.2.14.0: undefined reference to `clReleaseProgram'
/usr/bin/ld: ../library/libclFFT.so.2.14.0: undefined reference to `clGetProgramInfo'
/usr/bin/ld: ../library/libclFFT.so.2.14.0: undefined reference to `clCreateKernel'
/usr/bin/ld: ../library/libclFFT.so.2.14.0: undefined reference to `clCreateProgramWithSource'
/usr/bin/ld: ../library/libclFFT.so.2.14.0: undefined reference to `clReleaseKernel'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [examples/CMakeFiles/example_examples_fft2d.dir/build.make:85: examples/examples/fft2d] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:223: examples/CMakeFiles/example_examples_fft2d.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:152: all] Error 2
```

I don't understand where these errors could come from, it seems that the library `libclFFT.so.2.14.0` I have built doesn't contain the references to OpenCL basic functions (like `clGetPlatformIDs` or `clCreateCommandQueue`...).

Moreover, I don't know why the path of undefined reference is to the upper level, i.e `/usr/bin/ld: ../library/libclFFT.so.2.14.0`, because the library is built into `/opt/build/library` directory.

I would like to be able to compile fine the `libclFFT.so` that takes into account the OpenCL headers indicated by the path `OpenCL_INCLUDE_DIR` and library by `OpenCL_LIBRARY`.

I have to solve this issue of path taken by `cmake`, i.e : `../library/libclFFT.so.2.14.0`and include into the building of this library all the OpenCL functions from `AMDAPP`SDK.

Comment: What OS and compiler do you use?

Comment: Please call `make VERBOSE=1` - and you'll get compilation and linking commands. Probably you'll see how to solve your problem yourself after that... if not, please update your question with this new info

Comment: @HEKTO . Issue finally fixed on a MacOS Catalina but one just last question : how can I manage the installation of AMD APP SDK for OpenCL on MacOS, is it installed by default ? I didn't see a lot of documentation about this ? I realized that I had `/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework` and `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework`directories but I am not sure if I have to install another AMD APP SDK to get last OpenCL libraries ? Any help is welcome. Regards

Comment: I've never heard about using the AMD APP SDK on MacOS - I believe this (pretty obsolete) package was developed only for Windows and Linux. The MacOS has (or had?) its own implementation of OpenCL, which should be accessed with `-framework OpenCL` option

Comment: @HEKTO thanks, this is what I thought but not sure. Initially, I worked with AMD APP SDK OpenCL on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cmake` setup on your machine should have an OpenCL finder, which is called by the command `find_package(OpenCL)` when the `cmake` executes the `CMakeLists.txt` file from the `clFFT` distribution (this command can be used also in your own `CMakeLists.txt` files). This finder is simply a file, named `FindOpenCL.cmake`, which must be a part of the `cmake` configuration. Make sure you have this file:

```
find /usr -name FindOpenCL.cmake
```

If you have this finder you won't need to set variables `OpenCL_INCLUDE_DIR` and `OpenCL_LIBRARY` in the `cmake` call - the finder will find all the needed OpenCL paths. If you have this finder but it doesn't work correctly - then it'll be a question for its developers. If you *don't* have this finder then it'll be a problem in the `cmake` installation and/or setup. This finder is described [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindOpenCL.html).

According to our conversation in comments, you tried to use the AMD APP SDK v3.0 package on MacOS - this couldn't work because AMD supported only Windows and Linux operating systems. It's understandable because Apple has long history of its own OpenCL support - please see [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202823).